# If statement in Wordpress & Soliloquy

Tags: php, wordpress

Basically I'm looking to show the Soliloquy slider if the current page is the homepage, else show selected thumbnail, if there is no thumbnail then show default/fallback image.

I don't know much about PHP, I only know the bare basics, Where have I gone wrong with this code?

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
                    <?php  echo do_shortcode('[soliloquy id="1415"]'); ?>
                        <?php else : ?>
                            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(array(960,300));} ?>
                                <?php else { ?>
                                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/generic.jpg" />
                                <?php } ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: if one of the answers helped you;  please accept it!

Comment: Nope, none of these solutions are working

Comment: whats the remaining problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to print the bloginfo() function.

```
if ( is_home() ) { 
    if ( function_exists( 'soliloquy_slider' ) ) soliloquy_slider( '1415' );
} else {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        the_post_thumbnail(array(960,300));
    } else {  ?>
        <img src="<?=bloginfo('template_directory');?>/img/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
    <? 
   } 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write the if/else statement like this

```
<?php if ( is_home() ) : ?>
  // stuff for home here
<?php else : ?>
  // stuff for other pages here
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your img tag with below code

`<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/img/default.jpg" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />`